# How to calculate the number of days from Jan 1, 0000 to any specified date including leap years?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project in which the ultimate goal is to create a calendar for any month and year.  A part of the project requires that I first calculate the number of days from Jan 1, 0000 to any specified date. The function must take three parameters, representing year, month, and day. I am new to C++ so please cut me some slack if there is some incorrectly used commands or logic.  So far this is what I have but the numbers are off by a few days when I test it.  Can someone please tell me where my code went wrong?

```
int const day_of_forever(int const year, int const month, int const day)
 {
     int count[]={0,31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365};
     if ((year % 400==0) && (year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0 )&& (month>=2))
         ((count[month-1]+day)+1);
     return (count[month-1]+day)+(((year)*365)+1) +((year)/4)-(year/100)+(year/400);
 }

void main()
{ 
    int const year=2000;
    int const day=1;
    int const month=1;

    int const something=day_of_forever(year,month,day);
    print (something);
}
```

Comment: Mr. Debugging Tool can help you debug your program.  What was the outcome when you used the debugging tool?

Comment: You forgot to account for the [Calendar Act of 1752](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/year-text-British.html) and the various different dates various countries changed calendars. Also, your code states that all leap years are zero mod 400, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: You code may have failed at the beginning because the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: The statement associated with your `if` statement doesn't do anything.  No variables are assigned, no functions called.

Comment: Why do you have 13 items in that count array? I believe you should get rid of the zero

Comment: Your `return` statement performs almost the same amount of work that the expression of your `if` statement.

Comment: @Smac89:  The technique of 13 entries for the months is to eliminate the need to subtract 1 from the month number.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, OP is still subtracting 1

Comment: @Smac89: The OP needs to be consistent, either stop subtracting 1 or change the array to use 12 entries.

Comment: When you say "any specified date", specified according to what calendar? Julian? Gregorian? Proleptic Gregorian?

Comment: There is no January 1, 0000 because there is no year zero. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Some calendar systems retroactively define a year zero.

Comment: @KeithThompson - hmmm...based on a re-reading of "Calendrical Calculations" (Reingold, Edward and Dershowitz, Nachum), Millennium Edition (2001), page 50, second paragraph, in a discussion of the proleptic Gregorian calendar the authors state that "Unlike the Julian calendar, this proleptic calendar *does* have a year zero". They also note in a footnote on page 48 that the convention of 1 B.C. being followed by 1 A.D. is attributed to the Venerable Bede, who didn't know about zero. So as regards the proleptic Gregorian calendar, I stand corrected. :-)

Comment: The directions in the lab were to count the day including leap years from January 1, 0000 to a specified date. Those are not my rules it's in the lab assignment itself. I guess they made it that way so it would be easier to define where to start. I as well as the professor is aware that there is no January 1, 0000. I realize my logic was off so I tried two different things, one is contained in the if statement and the other is an equation. I posted a combination of both to get a feel of which way I should go. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'll let others debate whether years start at 0 or 1. But save yourself all that leap year headache - the proleptic Gregorian calendar repeats every 400 years -everything exactly to the dot - same day of week 4 same months same date, mod 400 years - e.g. July 29, 423 AD would also be a Saturday. **`( 365 x 4 + 1 ) x 100 - 4 + 1  := 146,097 days`** - There are exactly **`146097 days every 400 yrs`**. Only perform leap year calcs closer in. **`146,097 x 5  := 730485`**. 5 loop cycles later you've already tracked up to Dec-31, Year 2000.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem statement is ill-defined. You can't just say "any specified date" because many dates are ambiguous due to the various calendars in use at various places at various times. Perhaps you should stick to dates after 1800 to keep things manageable.

In any event, if you're trying to implement the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar):

1. You don't account for the [Calendar Act of 1752](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/year-text-British.html).
2. Your `if` statement doesn't do anything, it just adds 1 to something and throws that away.
3. The logic in your test for leap years is wrong. It says a leap year must be zero mod 400 AND a bunch of other stuff. But most [leap years](http://kalender-365.de/leap-years.php) are not zero mod 400.
4. The `+ - +` logic at the end of your `return` statement doesn't consider whether the date is before or after the leap day.
5. You don't account for Julian [leap days not in the proleptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Julian_and_proleptic_Gregorian_calendar_dates) Gregorian calendar. You may or may not need to, depending on how your input date is defined.
6. There was no year zero. So January 1, 0000 never happened.

Comment: 1752 is when the UK and possessions (including what is now the US) changed from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar. Much of Europe switched in 1582; other countries switched at various times up to the 20th century. If you're going to account for the change, you either need to include location information or acknowledge that your results are only application in certain places.

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree. This is a surprisingly hard problem. The naive problem statement hides this complexity with the phrase "any specified date", which of course isn't very well-defined. (I added some extra clarification about that.)

Comment: The directions in the lab were to count the day including leap years from January 1, 0000 to a specified date.  Those are not my rules it's in the lab assignment itself.  I guess they made it that way so it would be easier to define where to start.  I as well as the professor is aware that there is no January 1, 0000.  I realize my logic was off so I tried two different things, one is contained in the if statement and the other is an equation.  I posted a combination of both to get a feel of which way I should go.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your leap year test should be something like

```
if( (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) && month >= 2)
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: ```year % 4 = 0``` nice try